# query about function call in ethereum vyper

Tags: vyper

How the function will be called in vyper while compiling?, how the variables will be declared and how the data will be mapped to that variables?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code that your are trying to understand?

Comment: (: ([[]])

:()
: []
# = [ , , ]
@
 (:[],:):
   #  (.[] != ):
    .[]=
    . = *
    
@
@
 (:[]) ->:
     .[])